# c++ identical strings fail comparison check

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2012, compare

I have been stumped by this for a few days now. I am running a unit test on one of my classes to make sure everything is correct.

However I am encountering a very strange 'bug' when comparing the name of an object.
The name is set when I call constructor. The name is correctly set based on the notes I pass in. However in this one case the BOOST_CHECK fails

To show just how strange this is, here are the values of the two strings in the debugger:

```
Fdim.name() // "F Diminished"
BOOST_CHECK(Fdim.name() == "F Diminished");  // this fails
```

Here are the specs for the two strings, taken from debugger:

```
Fdim.name() 
// size - 12, capacity - 15, 
// chars: [70, 32, 68, 105, 109, 105, 110, 105, 115, 104, 101, 100]

"F Diminished" stored inside a variable (to see specs of string)
// size - 12, capacity - 15,
// chars: [70, 32, 68, 105, 109, 105, 110, 105, 115, 104, 101, 100]
```

As you can see the strings are identical, yet the == and .compare both fail.

Here is something even more strange:

```
std::string n = Fdim.name();
std::string r = "F Diminished";
unsigned val = n.compare(r);       // RETURNS 0, everytime
BOOST_CHECK(val == 0);             // fails 
BOOST_CHECK(val == ((unsigned) 0));// fails
```

I am completely dumbfounded. val always returns 0 when i compare the strings (so they are equal) but val != 0 when I compare?

Does anyone know what the problem could be?
Are there any attributes to a string I should know about that might throw off this comparison check?

**EDIT*******
The strings are being stored as std::string, i am not using char*, or cstring. member _name is std::string.

Here is the BOOST OUTPUT:

```
c:/directory etc(64): error in "ChordIdentification": check val == 0 failed
c:/directory etc(65): error in "ChordIdentification": check n == r failed
c:/directory etc(66): error in "ChordIdentification": check val == ((unsigned) 0) failed
c:/directory etc(67): error in "ChordIdentification": check Fdim.name() == "F Diminished" failed
```

Here is the code for the test case, just to make sure people know what val, n, and r are:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ChordIdentification)
{
MAKE_NOTE(Db, 'D', FLAT);   // macro that creates a note
MAKE_NOTE(F, 'F', NATURAL);
MAKE_NOTE(Ab, 'A', FLAT);
MAKE_NOTE(Cb, 'C', FLAT);

Chord DbMajor7 = Chord(Cb, Ab, F, Db);
Chord Fdim = Chord(Ab, Cb, F);

CHORD_TEST(DbMajor7, "Db Dominant7", MAJ, THIRD_INVERSION, DOMINANT7); macro of several boost tests, checking members. This test passes completely for this instance of chord. name() check is passed
std::string n = Fdim.name();
std::string r = "F Diminished";
unsigned val = n.compare(r);
//if (val == 0)
BOOST_CHECK(val == 0);
BOOST_CHECK(n == r);
BOOST_CHECK(Fdim.name() == std::string("F Diminished"));    // these strings fail to compare. no idea why, lengths are same, chars same?????
BOOST_CHECK(std::strcmp(Fdim.name(), "F Diminished") == 0);
CHORD_TEST(Fdim, "F Diminished", DIM, FIRST_INVERSION, DIMINISHED); // partially successful, again the string comparison is responsible for this
}
```

Comment: Can you produce a minimal but complete test case that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Are you storing the strings as char* pointers?  That would be the easiest explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Can you paste the output generated by BOOST_CHECK?

Comment: I can't really create a minimal test case, because the class I am testing on, is dependant on other classes, and those classes are also dependant on some global functions, etc. I would have to post the entire project for the test case to work.

Comment: What does ``std::cout << Fdim.name() == "F Diminished"`` produce?

Comment: If the `val == 0` check does not pass, how have you determined that `val` is always 0?

Comment: For all I know, you have a buffer overrun that manages to precisely break the unit test framework just before the failure. Or the source file that fails `#include`s something that conflicts with the framework. Without a reproducible test case, anyone's guess is as good as anyone else's. Have you tried to debug the framework itself? You may want to run your source through the preprocessor and examine what `BOOST_CHECK` expands to.

Comment: @hvd, the debugger tells me that val is = 0.

Comment: What does `Choord(Ab, Cb, F)` function actually look like? Have you tried printing the actual `Fdim.name()` string? Is there a space somewhere at the end?

Comment: @n.m. How would I go about debugging the framework? Also to note, that an if statement will also fail. So it is not just boost here either. Its any comparison.  I will try to cout the name now

Comment: @David In that case, it's more likely that the compiler has compiled the code in such a way that the debugger can no longer correctly retrieve the value of `val`. Could you try printing `val`, as well as `Fdim.name()`?

Comment: Like any other thing: use a debugger, step into functions and examine variables.

Comment: @juanchopanza It turns out the cout << is F Diminished7 , so that seems to explain why the strings failed. But why does the debugger tell me it is F Diminished? val prints out a 1. Guess this means I cant trust the debugger anymore...

Comment: The debugger is obviously tone deaf.

Comment: Rightly so... Gah, now I must debug the good old fashioned way...

Comment: What compiler/debugger are you using?

Comment: The default one that comes with Visual Studio 2012. I am assuming this is latest VC++

Comment: I think this is a buffer overflow problem. Because the functions tell me that the chord is indeed "F Diminished"...

Comment: Or the debuggers is only showing the first n characters of the string. That's not unusual...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have finally discovered why this was happening. It was to do with the fact that the debugger could not determine what instance of child class it was trying to evaluate.

The chord's are being identified via a map, with a polymorphic key, with an abstract base class (Composite_Key), child (Composite_Key_2Intervals) and Child from that child (Composite_Key_3Intervals)

What was failing, was the fact that any sort of test on whether or not a key was indeed 3 intervals, or 2, was always returning true, because 3intervals : 2intervals. The compiler was not able to pick up on this, and always gave back the wrong value found in the look up table.

Also, the map never sorted in debugger mode, so the order that the keys were inserted stayed the same. However in reality they were being reshuffled, which caused the whole evaluation while debugging to be completely false.

To fix this, I now made sure that these two classes only inherit from the abstract base, so that they are not related in any way to each other. Now all tests pass and everything comes back true.

This cause of this problem was solely the debugger. It did not evaluate appropriately.

Comment: It's sad that you can't accept your own answer at your rep level. But, it's pretty easy to get a few hundred rep around here if you actually know your stuff reasonably well. :-)

Comment: Meh, Im just glad it was solved. I will admit for a while though, I thought the compiler was telling me a message like 'Go to sleep! Im tired!'. Good thing it wasn't me going crazy...

Answer (score 2):

If we look at this:

```
BOOST_CHECK(Fdim.name() == "F Diminished")
```

then Fdim.name() is a C style string, I expect, and as such just a pointer to a character array - the address of that character array is (most likely) not the same address as the literal string in your `BOOST_CHECK()`.

You can fix it by:

```
BOOST_CHECK(Fdim.name() == string("F Diminished"))
```

or

```
BOOST_CHECK(strcmp(Fdim.name(), "F Diminished") == 0)
```

Comment: @CAFxX actually, it has an implicit constructor that takes ``const char*``, otherwise the string literal would always have to be on the RHS of the comparison.

Comment: Both of these do not work. Comparison still fails. The second method using strcmp tells me that Fdim.name() is std::string, and no suitable  conversion exists to convert to const char *

Comment: Then we need to see your fdim.name() function, and the declaration of whatever members it returns.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: How about `BOOST_CHECK(Fdim.name().c_str() == "F Diminished")`?

Comment: That will definitely fail in the way I described above - the strings are compared as pointers, not as strings. So unless c_str() returns the same address as "F Diminished", then it will fail - and unless "F Diminished" is the exact same string used in both places, it's unlikely to give the same address.